# explicitly defining Margin in chrome

Tags: asp.net, css, google-chrome, w3c, dhtml

I have a div on a page, the buttons on other browsers are neatly placed but on chrome, they are falling down.
I am aware of explicit hacks for IE 7 which is like *Margin, but not aware about chrome.Is there a way to define in css.
i dont want conditional statements to deal with this.I need to explicitly mention margin in negative pixels for chrome to pull the buttons up.

Comment: Probably your problem is your CSS, not Webkit.

Answer (score 0):

This jQuery should add class="chrome" to the html element of your document.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Mac OS X') != -1) {
      if (/chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())) { $('html').addClass('chrome'); }
 } else {

      if (/chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())) { $('html').addClass('chrome'); }
 }
});
```

You can then target the div like so:

```
.div {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
html.chrome .div {
     margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: thanks for this mate...but i had to do it just with css...please look below to see what made it work in css.

Answer (score 0):

this worked like a charm

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
/* Safari and Chrome */
.act .now {
    margin: -14%  auto 0px;

}

/* Safari only override */
::i-block-chrome,.act .now {
    margin: 5% auto 0px;
}}
```